# Rails autocomplete and acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

I hope for help to follow problem.
I have install gem rails3-jquery-autocomplete from [here](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)

and gem "acts-as-taggable-on" from [here](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on)

Here is my history:

my model is

```
class Article <ActiveRecord::Base
       acts_as_taggable_on :tags
       attr_accessible :title, :body, :tag_list
```

my controller is

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
     autocomplete :tag, :name, :class_name => 'ActAsTaggableOn::Tag'
     def tag_cloud
            @tags ||=Article.tag_counts_on(:tags)
     end
     def all
        @tags = Article.tag_counts_on(:tags).limit(8).order('count desc')
        klass = Article
        klass = klass.tagged_with(@tag) if (@tag = params[:tag]).present?
        @articles = klass.where(:state => '4').paginate(:page => params[:page])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html  # index.html.erb
            format.xml  { render :xml => @articles }
        end
    end
```

my route is

```
resources :articles do
    collection do
    get 'autocomplete_tag_name' 
    get 'about'
    get 'all'
    get 'myarticles'
    delete 'destroy'
            end
end
```

my _form.html.erb

```
<div class="field">
           <label for="tag_list">Κατηγορία (Μπορείτε να προσθέσετε διαφορετικές κατηγορίες διαχωρίζοντάς τες με κόμμα)</label><br />
           <%= f.autocomplete_field :tag_list, autocomplete_tag_name_articles_path, :"data-delimiter" => ', ' %>
</div>
```

my index.html.erb

```
<div class='tag-box'>
          <% @tags.sort_by(&:count).reverse.each do |k| %>
                    <% url_opts = {:action => "all", :controller => "articles"}
                    link_name = "#{k.name} (#{k.count})" %>
                    <% if @tag == k.name %>
                             <%= link_to link_name, url_opts.merge(:tag => nil), :class => "tag current_tag", :title => "Κλικ για εμφάνιση όλων" %>
                    <% else %>
                             <%= link_to link_name,  url_opts.merge(:tag => k.name), :class => "tag", :title => "Κλικ για εμφάνιση άρθρων στην κατηγορία #{k.name}" %>
                    <% end %>
          <% end %>
</div>
```

my application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery-1.7.2.min.js', 'jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.min.js', 'autocomplete-rails.js', 'rails.js'  %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css' %>
```

and last my Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.11'
gem 'pg'
gem 'jquery-rails', '>= 1.0.12'
gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on', '~> 2.2.2'
```

in app works the tagging system but don't work the autocomplete.

perhaps my problem is on file _form.html.erb. I have on file new.html.erb the code

```
<section id="myarticles">
     <h2>Νέο άρθρο</h2>
      <%= render 'form' %>
</section>
```

Is about render and autocomplete together and autocomplete don't work?

Comment: Is there an error on the Rails logs?

Comment: thanks for replaying me. I have the follow statments:           Started GET "/stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-05-02 20:13:43 +0300

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css"):
  

Rendered /home/konstantinos/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@rails3tutorial/gems/actionpack-3.0.11/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (6.2ms)

Answer (score 3):

Finaly the solution for my problem that can help someone with the same situation is simple.
Copy the file jquery-ui-1.8.19.custom.css from `public/stylesheets/ui-lightness` or from `public/stylesheets/smoothness` depends from the download theme from [jQuery UI-Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/)

and paste to public/stylesheets/ and automagicaly disappeared the Routing Error and voila the Autocomplete functioning.

I had follow the instructions from [here](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete-app)

> Copy the files on the css folder to the public/stylesheets folder on your app. Note that these files may be one level down from the css folder, in a folder called "ui-lightness".

but the right position is on directory public/stylesheets.
Also remove from mycontroller the follow code `:class_name => 'ActAsTaggableOn::Tag'` and now the code looks like

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
          autocomplete :tag, :name
```